# Can Stanford CoreNLP lemmatise a word given a custom POS?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to lemmatise a given word multiple times, with different POS supplied.

For example, the lemma of "met" is "meet" (POS: verb), while the lemma of "meeting" is "meeting" (POS: noun).

But if "meeting" is a verb, the lemma is "meet". I would like then to lemmatise "meeting" with a given verb POS, in an effort to find such similarities.

Is this possible?

Using latest Java CoreNLP 3.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the method `String lemma(String word, String tag)` in `edu.stanford.nlp.process.Morphology`.

```
Morphology morphology = new Morphology();

String word = "meeting";
String tag = "VB";
String lemma = morphology.lemma(word, tag);
System.out.println(String.format("%s_%s   %s", word, tag, lemma));
```